# Can i add few files for some remote repo only in git

Tags: git, version-control

I have the git repo and i have two `remote repos` one is `deafult` and other `backup`

I push to other branch by

`git push backup`

Now i have folder called `backupfiles` which i don't want to push in `deafult` but i do want it to be avaiable in `backup` repo

is there any way

Answer (score 0):

You can choose which refs (branches, tags etc) you push to or fetch from another repository, but the files committed in the history of a ref are non-negotiable (unless you change the history with e.g. `git filter-branch`). You could create another branch where you commit the files in the `backupfiles` directory and push that branch to a subset of your remote repositories.